# Django API key hide

Tags: python, django

I have a mapping application being developed in django. It pulls maps from bing to display on the site. So I have bing api key shown in my js file. I am planning to make the project available on github. But the issue is I don't want people retrieving maps from my api key. They should register for themselves. How should I go about doing this? Putting the key in `settings.py` won't work. I could put the key inside my `local_settings.py` but then I would have to manually provide key to any trusted developer who joins the project. I want a simpler way to do this. Maybe all developers with committing access get the api key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Two Scoop of Django](https://django.2scoops.org/) recommends that no API credentials are stored inside of python, or put in version control, they recommend all keys exist as environmentally variables on your server.

The above way is not the way I usually handle API keys in my projects, though. I store them in my settings.py files and put them under version control.

What is wrong with storing them in your local_settings.py and providing them to a approved developers?

You have to manually approve developers so it is not like it is much more difficult to provide them with credentials they need to develop on your application.  You could also just require they sign up for their own bing api keys for development?

Comment: There are many admins using our org's github account. I usually don't know if someone has been given committing access to manually provide them the keys. So just wanted to automate the process.